# List of Symbols not printing in same page

Tags: header-footer

The list of symbols not printing in same page after the "List of Symbols" heading like in 1st figure. Rather it prints in next page just like the 2nd figure.
The MWE is:

```
        \documentclass[a4paper,openany]{report}
        \usepackage[acronym,section,nomain]{glossaries}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{}
        \makeglossaries
        \newglossaryentry{symb:C}
         {name={\ensuremath{C}},description={SVM Tuning Parameter},
          sort=symbolc,type=symbolslist}
        \newglossaryentry{symb:c1}{name={\ensuremath{c_b}},
          description={Optimal Number of Cluster Center}, 
          sort=symbolcent, type=symbolslist}
        \newglossaryentry{symb:d}{name={\ensuremath{D}},
           description={Dataset},sort=symbold,type=symbolslist}
        \newglossaryentry{symb:c}{name={\ensuremath{c}},
            description={Number of Cluster Center}, 
            sort=symbolcen,type=symbolslist}
        \setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
        \lhead[\sl\leftmark]{\sl\leftmark}
        \rhead[\rm]{\rm}
        \begin{document}
         \chapter*{List of Symbols}
           \gls{symb:c}, \gls{symb:C}, \gls{symb:d}, \gls{symb:c1}
          \printglossary[type=symbolslist]
         \end{document}
```

1st image is blank having only the heading.
[image: symbols1]

2nd image starts from underline and symbols are printing
[image: symbols2]

Please help anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `title=` option of `\printglossaries` and remove the `\chapter*{List of ...}`.

Also don't use `\sl` and `\rm` commands, they are outdated. In addition, load `glossaries` as the last package here, even after `hyperref`, if needed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[acronym,section,nomain]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{symb:C}
{name={\ensuremath{C}},description={SVM Tuning Parameter},
  sort=symbolc,type=symbolslist}
\newglossaryentry{symb:c1}{name={\ensuremath{c_b}},
  description={Optimal Number of Cluster Center}, 
  sort=symbolcent, type=symbolslist}
\newglossaryentry{symb:d}{name={\ensuremath{D}},
  description={Dataset},sort=symbold,type=symbolslist}
\newglossaryentry{symb:c}{name={\ensuremath{c}},
  description={Number of Cluster Center}, 
  sort=symbolcen,type=symbolslist}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
\lhead[\slshape\leftmark]{\slshape\leftmark}
\rhead[\rmfamily]{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Foo}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Foo section}

%\chapter*{List of Symbols}
\gls{symb:c}, \gls{symb:C}, \gls{symb:d}, \gls{symb:c1}
\cleardoublepage
\printglossary[title={List of Symbols},type=symbolslist]
\end{document}
```